# 27.5 x 2.00 tyre, is different width a problem

Tags: tire

like i said i have a 27.5 inch by either 2.2 or 2.0 (rather 2.0 but i'm not 100% sure) width and there aren't many tires with size 2.0 in shops at my place. Probably will go with a different width and i want to Ask is that fine. For ex. 2.2 inches. Will that fit fine? I want to go tubeless too. Which tyre will be good for dry terrain and asphalt under 40€?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bicycles . We recommend that new members [take the tour](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) to get to know how to make best use of the site. If you do a search for [tyre width](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=tyre+width) using the search box on the top right of the page you will find a number of similar questions. We can't give you shopping recommendations because they are so specific to you, right now, where you are.

Answer (score 0):

We don't recommend specific products here but you should have no issue as long as you don't try to make a huge jump in size and so as long as your frame has enough clearance. Changing between 2.00 and 2.20 should be fine going either direction (assuming tire clearance is not an issue).

The switch to tubeless is another task but also not too difficult but will involve setting the existing rim up for it with tape and sealant.